# $J=X^TPX$ , getting P from this formula

Tags: linear-algebra, matrix-equations

I have a formula

$J=X^TPX$

P is n x n matrix

X is n x 1 matrix

J and X are known, how do I get P?

Comment: I am not sure if the solution is unique, but $J$ is a number, so we can set $P:= \frac{J}{|X|^4} XX^T$ which is a $n \times n$-matrix and then we have $X^TPX = \frac{J}{|X|^4}X^TXX^TX = J$ if $X \ne 0$. If $X=0$ we have $J=0$ and can choose any matrix $P$.

Comment: Welcome to [math.se] SE. Take a [tour]. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Answer (score 0):

With a single $X$ and $J$, you can't. For instance
$$
\begin{bmatrix} 1\\0\end{bmatrix} ^T\begin{bmatrix} a&b\\ c&d\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} 1\\0\end{bmatrix}=a.
$$
You are completely free to choose $b,c,d$.

Conceptually, $J$ is a single number and $P$ is determined by $n^2$ numbers.